# Meta tags don't work for "custom content type"

Tags: 7, meta-tags

The keywords and descriptions I type show up on all standard pages (articles, basic pages, etc), but they do not show up on any custom content types. All I see are the default meta-tags without the keywords and description that I type. My website contains several custom content types and all have the same behavior. I tried a few different themes and they are still missing.

Someone suggested to add `render($content['metatags']);` to see the meta-tags.

Can anybody suggest to which file I need to add that line? I am creating the custom content type using the admin panel in Drupal 7.

Comment: The "standard pages" are content types exactly like the ones you can create yourself. They have no magic added to them, they are just conveniently created during install. There must be some configuration specific to your site that causes the issue, and I don't expect anyone to be able to answer this question without more information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I figured it was just the front page that is causing this issue. I was able to set the front page meta data using admin->config->search and meta -> global-> global: front page. Now everything works.

Comment: @ybkishore: Please add your solution as an answer.